# Can't consume webservice from Java

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I created the webservice stubs using axis2-1.5's wsdl2java.bat. This created a src folder with the following structure in it:

```
src/net/mycompany/www/services/SessionIntegrationStub.java
```

The package of the SessionIntegration.java file is: package net.mycompany.www.services;

Now, I am trying to use this stub in my java code. I placed my java file in the same services folder. I set the same package. Here is my entire class:

```
package net.mycompany.www.services;
import net.mycompany.www.services;

public class DynamicProxy 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    try 
    {
      SessionIntegrationStub stub = new SessionIntegrationStub();
      System.out.println(stub.getSessionIntegration("test"));
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    } 
  } 
}
```

Then I tried to compile this code with the following cmd:

```
javac DynamicProxy.java
```

However I keep getting this error message:

```
C:\data\net\mycompany\www\services>javac DynamicProxy.java
DynamicProxy.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SessionIntegrationStub
location: package net.mycompany.www.services
import net.mycompany.www.services.SessionIntegrationStub;
                                       ^
DynamicProxy.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SessionIntegrationStub
location: class net.mycompany.www.services.DynamicProxy
                        SessionIntegrationStub stub = new SessionIntegrationStub();
                        ^
DynamicProxy.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SessionIntegrationStub
location: class net.mycompany.www.services.DynamicProxy
                        SessionIntegrationStub stub = new SessionIntegrationStub();
                                                          ^
3 errors
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

**Update 1:**

I compiled the stubs (thanks to the answers below) and I got rid of the first error. I changed the import to this import net.americanapparel.www.services.*; however I still get an error for the SessionIntegrationStub: cannot find symbol. I also tried this import: net.americanapparel.www.services.SessionIntegrationStub, but that did not help either. Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: In which folder (from root folder of project) is `SessionIntegrationStub` and if `SessionIntegrationStub` is compiled, where (folder) is the `.class` file situated?

Comment: All files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile your stub first or both together, since wsdl2java only creates a `.java` file, not the `.class` file. The compiler error clearly  says it don't know the SessionIntegrationStub.

The other answer is right too: you have to

```
import net.mycompany.www.services.*;
```

not

```
import net.mycompany.www.services;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to import it.

```
import net.mycompany.www.services.SessionIntegrationStub;
```

should do the trick.

and then:

```
shell$ javac my/package/*.java
```

which should enable javac to find or compile all the files it needs.

Comment: Still doesnt work. I am getting the same errors as in Update 1.

Comment: Javac can see the package but not the class. However I can see the SessionIntegrationStub.class file. I am surely missing something here.

Comment: Well, it should be on the classpath. That's why I suggested compiling all files in 1 batch (javac ...*)

Comment: Ok. I did. Now I get this when I try to execute the .class file: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: C:\data\net\mycompany\www\services\dynamicproxy/java Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\data\net\mycompany\www\ser
vices\dynamicproxy.java. I compiled all java files like this: javac -cp . C:\data\net\mycompany\www\services\*.java

Comment: Forgot to mention: I am trying to run it like that as well: javac -cp . C:\data\net\mycompany\www\services\dynamicproxy